# NGUI UISprite sprite Not Shown If Shader is Unlit/Transparent Colored

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, ngui

I have a problem to display the sliced sprite from atlas in the grid, the shader is using Unlit/Transparent Colored. 
All sprites were not shown, as this:
[image]

When i changed the shader to Unlit/ Transparent Cutout, the sprites can be shown, as this:
[image]

What's the problem here? I can't use Unlit/ Transparent Cutout, it will make other layout messy. Can anyone help?

In my C# script, the sprite is set:

```
string sprite = sprites[type - 1];
GameObject instance = NGUITools.AddChild(grid, matchItemPrefab) as GameObject;
instance.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = sprite;
```

Comment: Seems like a depth problem.. Did you check your sprite's depth, the corresponding panel's depth and maybe the render queue of all involved shaders (so, for the icons and background).

Comment: Thanks, it is depth issue!

Comment: You're welcome. World be nice if you could post your fix as an answer, so that others running in the same issues can find this for help.